# How to install gail and atk-bridge?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm trying to run [import.io](https://import.io/) on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. It says

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

In synaptic they seem installed, which is confusing, unless I'm looking at different packages. So I wounder how to install them using `apt-get`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem with gvim in 16.04. There, the 64bit libraries helped:

```
apt-get install libatk-adaptor libgail-common
```

Comment: Bingo! The same decision is for the PCManFM app on a pure Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: This didn't work for me, nor did the 32-bit packages

Answer (score 37):

Packages You are looking for are in i386 arch;

`apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386`

Comment: This fixes one flavor of  steam crash-on-login problems as well.

Comment: This command allowed Steam to run on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: This fixed one of the Steam boot errors for me as well, Mint 20.2 (Ubuntu 20.04).