# Steam Isnt working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, opengl

```
tyler@Tyler:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
assert_20180705192828_1.dmp[5672]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20180705192828_1.dmp
/home/tyler/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 876:  5656 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20180705192828_1.dmp[5672]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20180705192828_1.dmp[5672]: response: CrashID=bp-7655b994-a255-4453-9e26-828ee2180705
assert_20180705192828_1.dmp[5672]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20180705192828_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-7655b994-a255-4453-9e26-828ee2180705''
```

GPU  INFO 940M using 384.130 Nvidia Binary Drivers

Answer (score 0):

try these links they might help you solve your problem

You seem to be missing the swarst driver so here's a link to some help with it
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/failed-to-load-driver-swrast-4175497461/

And try installing the 32bit version of gail and atk-bridge it worked fine for me
[How to install gail and atk-bridge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge)

Comment: Hello. Can you please add the relevant details here? Links sometimes die out when websites go down for a while, disappear, or switch to a new URL scheme.

Comment: Trying to install gail and atk bridge failed as the system showed they were already installed. Can you send a better guide for swarst driver installation?