# Snap install of "instagraph" works but can't log in even after changing password

Tags: login, snap, 19.10, instagram

I wanted an Instagram client that would run on my Ubuntu 19.10 Gnome desktop; I found out that the app "Instagraph" can be installed with snap, so I went ahead and did so using:

---

```
sudo snap install instagraph
```

After this, I ran the app from the command line so that I could see if any errors occurred:

---

```
instagraph
```

What I got was this:

---

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols 
specified are supported
OffscreenRenderer::OffscreenRenderer(QObject*)
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) 
propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this 
message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" 
(uid=1000 pid=19917 
comm=\"/snap/instagraph/86/opt/Instagraph/bin/Instagraph \" 
label=\"snap.instagraph.instagraph (enforce)\") 
interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties\" member=\"GetAll\" error 
name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" 
destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=846 
comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) nmReply 
"An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to 
this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" (uid=1000 
pid=19917 comm=\"/snap/instagraph/86/opt/Instagraph/bin/Instagraph \" 
label=\"snap.instagraph.instagraph (enforce)\") 
interface=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" member=\"GetDevices\" 
error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" 
destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=846 
comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
"Object path cannot be empty"
UCUriHandler: Empty "APP_ID" environment variable, ignoring.
qrc:///Main.qml:104: TypeError: Cannot read property '__clarityFilter' 
of null
file:///snap/instagraph/86/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:108:25: Unable to assign 
[undefined] to QFont
file:///snap/instagraph/86/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:103:33: Unable to assign 
[undefined] to QQuickGradient*
file:///snap/instagraph/86/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:92:27: Unable to assign 
[undefined] to QColor
APP_ID isn't set, the handler ignored
qml: challenge_required
qml: login failed
APP_ID isn't set, the handler ignored
```

After resetting my Instagram password via email authentication and the Instagram website, closing the app and rerunning it from the command line several times, I kept getting the same error, and no login. Instagram prompted me with several security codes and messages that an unidentified device was attempting to log into my account, and asking me to affirm that it was me. I did so. Still unable to log in.

As someone who avoids using Snap whenever possible, and who may/may not have a full understanding of the syntax involved, I'd like to know if anyone has a fix that I could run, or if anyone else's encountered the same issue before and solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your error messages! The first few:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols 
specified are supported
OffscreenRenderer::OffscreenRenderer(QObject*)
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) 
propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this 
message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" (uid=1000 pid=19917
```

*Should* tell you that you're missing some authentication modules ( `gail`, `atk-bridge`, `canberra-gtk-module`), and that later attempts at authentication will fail ("`Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`").

Subsequent error messages, like:

```
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) 
    propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this 
    message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" (uid=1000 pid=19917
```

Are just the results of failing authentication, propagating through `instagraph` startup.

This question has been seen before, and has a well-liked answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge).